# Why do I get an error running JUnit tests on the 3rd time this code is executed?

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, h2

I have almost identical code in the `setUp()` method of three tests. When run individually, the tests all work, but when I run them as part of the complete set of tests, the last one fails.

The "offending" code is:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    AnnotationConfiguration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();

    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.h2.Driver");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:h2:mem");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext");

    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

    sessionFactory.openSession();

    // This is where it dies:
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername("emanymton");
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encodePassword("password", null));
    user.setAccess(1);

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
}
```

The stack trace is:

```
1    [main] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - schema export unsuccessful ava.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:mem
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1385)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
    at [MYPROJECT].security.authentication.manager.CustomAuthenticationManagerTest.setUp(CustomAuthenticationManagerTest.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
7    [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:mem
```

I'm using Maven for dependencies, and have the dependency com.h2database.h2, version 1.3.168 in my classpath. As mentioned before, it works fine in the previous two tests, just fails here.

Any ideas?

Cheers in advance

**EDIT:**

This is my `tearDown` for this Test:

```
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    try {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //
    }
    sessionFactory.close();
}
```

I've commented out the other two tests, and this one still fails, but ONLY if it's run as one of many, it runs Fine wen run on it's own.

**EDIT 2:**

I managed to get past some of the Driver issue when I commented out the line:

```
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext");
```

Not sure it this is a red herring, but for testing, is there a better class to use for the context class?

Comment: are you properly tearing down?

Comment: Not sure really, but I've got a simple rollback on the transaction: sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback(); I have tried closing the sessions, but nothing. It's also odd that the second instance works, and that it only happens on the third test. What is the reccommended way of destroying the session? I've assumed it's a simple session.close()?

Comment: Yeah, like Matt said, I also had one of these weird errors once, was a problem with the test teardown. Double check it, errors because of it are a pain.

Comment: You see, this makes sense to me - it looks like a poorly closed sessionFactory instance or similar, but I've commented out the other tests, and same error, but not when I run it alone

Comment: Hmm... Any reason for building `SessionFactory` on each test?

Comment: Not really, I will move it to the setupBeforeClass once I'm happy it works. There is only one test here anyway at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Being not sure what you are doing in the other two tests, I can only speculate the below reason

There might be some method in the 2nd test that is making the session either un available and this could have been caused because of some data you have inserted in the first test.As it is running good individually, some persist method in the second test is failing ( because of some thing like primary key already exists) which is messing up the session state and the exception is not caught properly to be shown in console.